# Obtain watershed shapefile from API

Tags: r, api

I am currently working with the APIs `modelmywatershed.org/api` and `https://modelmywatershed.org/api/docs/` trying to delineate a watershed for a given location.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

headers = c(
  `accept` = 'application/json',
  `Authorization` = 'Token {Insert API Code Here}',
  `Content-Type` = 'application/json',
  `X-CSRFToken` = '9P7k41yjWNqVtysnv8iv2KfeW4vadHih1wKZWkN41Mln249QxEZVZHwfvKcufvBO',
  'Accept-Encoding' = 'gzip,deflate'
)

data = '{  "location": [35.66735774,-102.4819484],  
"snappingOn": true,  "simplify": 0.0001,  "dataSource": "nhd"}'

# Watershed Delineation
res <-
  httr::POST(url = 'https://modelmywatershed.org/api/watershed/',
             httr::add_headers(.headers = headers),
             body = data, verbose())

api_char <- rawToChar(res$content)

api_JSON <- jsonlite::fromJSON(api_char, flatten = TRUE)
api_JSON

$job
[1] "0aa85683-37d4-4cb2-9b8c-5c1ee81c23fa"

$status
[1] "started"

job_ID <- api_JSON$job
job_ID 
#"0aa85683-37d4-4cb2-9b8c-5c1ee81c23fa"
```

I managed to get the `job_ID` and was able to get the information for the watershed

```
headers_watershed = c(`accept` = 'application/json',
                      `Authorization` = ' Token {Insert API Key Here}',
                      `X-CSRFToken` = '1I2YxuQlHlxpxPM09qZTlT6vEuFgucuaTpFDpN56MksR6lttbWGjiQnwdamAw0NH'
)

url_1 <-paste0(URL='https://modelmywatershed.org/api/jobs/', job_ID, '/')

res_job <- GET(url=url_1, 
            add_headers(.headers = headers_watershed))

Watershed_char <- rawToChar(res_job$content)

Watershed_JSON <- jsonlite::fromJSON(Watershed_char, flatten = TRUE)
```

```
####################
# Watershed Result #
####################

$job_uuid
[1] "0aa85683-37d4-4cb2-9b8c-5c1ee81c23fa"

$status
[1] "complete"

$result
$result$input_pt
$result$input_pt$geometry
$result$input_pt$geometry$coordinates
[1] -102.48203   35.66726

$result$input_pt$geometry$type
[1] "Point"


$result$input_pt$properties
$result$input_pt$properties$DistStr_m
[1] 0

$result$input_pt$properties$Dist_moved
[1] 0

$result$input_pt$properties$ID
[1] 1

$result$input_pt$properties$Lat
[1] 35.66736

$result$input_pt$properties$Lon
[1] -102.4819


$result$input_pt$type
[1] "Feature"

$result$watershed
$result$watershed$geometry
$result$watershed$geometry$coordinates
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 2 matrix slice(s) ]

$result$watershed$geometry$type
[1] "Polygon"

$result$watershed$properties
$result$watershed$properties$Area_km2
[1] 3475.114

$result$watershed$properties$GRIDCODE
NULL

$result$watershed$type
[1] "Feature"

$error
[1] ""

$started
[1] "2022-02-28T21:45:41.597568Z"

$finished
[1] "2022-02-28T21:45:56.052379Z"
```

However the issue is that I do not know how to download the information. Typically, the website produces a `.zip` file with all the necessary components of a shapefile, but I am struggling on how to create the zipfile to download the information.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what the issue might be, but you probably don't want to be posting those tokens publicly unless they're from API demos

Comment: If you would like to check linked API doc, it states: `All analyze and watershed endpoints return a Job Started Response on success. This response has a job value [...].
The jobs endpoint has a status key, whose value is either started, complete, or failed.` All you have to do is to wait until the job finishes (with status complete) and get the data. How to get the data is described as well under `​/jobs​/{job_uuid}​/` part of API DOC.

Comment: @camille, yes they are just API Demos. the job id is simply a random output

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko Thank you, I had a look, and actually updated the question because of it, however, the JOBS tab still does not explain how I am to download the file to the computer to be used.

Comment: @JayAntonioOliver, according to doc it returns a application/json type, not .zip file. I suspect, the .zip with shapefile is created on server when you access the data thru webpage. From `Watershed_JSON <- jsonlite::fromJSON[...]` it seems, that in fact a json is returned with `Point` and `Polygon` features. I would try to read them with `st_read()` from `sf`. Then you can write it to shapefile with `st_write()`

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko I tried using `st_read`. However, I get the following error
```R
Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  : 
  Expecting a single value: [extent=6].
In addition: Warning message:
In if (nchar(dsn) < 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```